# c++ how to pass a function to a timer?

Tags: timer, c++-cli

timer.h

```
#ifndef TIMERHPP
#define TIMERHPP
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>
class Timer1 {
public:
    Timer1();
    void add(std::chrono::milliseconds delay,
        std::function<void()> callback,
        bool asynchronous = true);
};
#endif
```

timer.cpp

```
#include "timer.h"
#include <thread>
Timer1::Timer1() {
}
void Timer1::add(std::chrono::milliseconds delay,
    std::function<void()> callback,
    bool asynchronous) {
    if (asynchronous) {
        std::thread([=]() {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(delay));
            callback();
            }).detach();
    }
    else {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(delay));
        callback();
    }
}
```

(I'm sorry, I've never worked with timers before.Sorry if the question is stupid.)
I have the following function that I want to pass to the timer:

```
System::Void Practform::MyForm::draw1() {
. . .
}
```

main.cpp

```
...
      Timer1 timer;
    
      timer.add(std::chrono::milliseconds(500), std::function<draw1>);
    ...
```

But I got the following errors:

E0254 the use of the type name is not allowed

E0757 function "Practform::MyForm::draw 1" is not a type name

please tell me what I did wrong? Something needs to be changed in the timer itself (I used the timer description from the guidelines)?

I will be very grateful for your help!

upd:

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Drawing;

[STAThreadAttribute]
void main(array<String^>^ args)
{
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Practform::MyForm form;
    Application::Run(% form);

}

. . .
 System::Void Practform::MyForm::draw1() {
     // Timer1 timer;

     int unit = 35;
     int pW = pictureBox1->Width;
     int pH = pictureBox1->Height;

     Bitmap^ img = gcnew Bitmap(pW, pH); 

     Graphics^ g = Graphics::FromImage(img); 

     for (int i = 0; i < pW; i += unit)

         g->DrawLine(Pens::LightGray, i, 0, i, pH);
     for (int i = 0; i < pH; i += unit)
         g->DrawLine(Pens::LightGray, 0, i, pW, i);

     Pen^ BlackPen = gcnew Pen(Brushes::Black);
     BlackPen->Width = 3.0F;
     int mX = int(pW / 2 - pW / 2 % unit);
     int mY = int(pH / 2 - pH / 2 % unit);
     g->DrawLine(BlackPen, mX, 0, mX, pH);
     g->DrawLine(BlackPen, 0, mY, pW, mY);

     g->ScaleTransform(1, -1); 

     g->TranslateTransform((float)mX, -(float)mY); 

     float x1 = -7.5f, x2 = 7.5f, s = 0.2f;
     float x = x1; 
     float y;

     System::Collections::Generic::List<PointF>^ ponts = gcnew System::Collections::Generic::List<PointF>(); 

     while (x < x2)
     {


         y = (double)fcnPtr(x);

         ponts->Add(PointF(x * (double)unit, y * (double)unit)); 

         x += s;

     }

     g->DrawLines(Pens::Green, ponts->ToArray()); 
     
     delete g; 

     this->pictureBox1->Image = img; 
 }
...
 System::Void Practform::MyForm::draw_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)
 {
      Timer1 timer;
      
    
      timer.add(std::chrono::milliseconds(500), std::function<draw1>);
 }
```

Comment: is `MyForm` a class? You need an object to call a member funciton

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number yes, it's class.

Comment: please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I have supplemented my question with a code.

Comment: Or you could use the [Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=netframework-4.6) class.

Answer (score 0):

A (non-static) member function is not the same as a non-member function. The major difference is that the member function needs an object to be called on, which your time class doesn't provide for.

A (somewhat) simple solution is the use of *user-data* pointers, which is passed to the call-back function. Then you can pass a pointer to the object as this user-data, and use a *static* member function wrapper to call the actual function.

Perhaps something like this:

```
class Timer1 {
public:
    void add(std::chrono::milliseconds delay,
        std::function<void(void*)> callback,
        void* user_data_ptr,
        bool asynchronous = true);
    ...
};


...

void Timer1::add(std::chrono::milliseconds delay,
    std::function<void(void*)> callback,
    void* user_data_ptr,
    bool asynchronous) {
    if (asynchronous) {
        std::thread([=]() {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(delay));
            callback(user_data_ptr);
            }).detach();
    }
    else {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(delay));
        callback(user_data_ptr);
    }
}
```

You then use it like:

```
class MyForm{
public:
    ...

    static System::Void draw_wrapper(void* object) {
        reinterpret_cast<MyForm*>(object)->draw1();
    }

    ...
};

...

System::Void Practform::MyForm::draw_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)
{
    Timer1 timer;
    timer.add(std::chrono::milliseconds(500), &MyForm::draw_wrapper, this);
}
```

Note that we use the `static` member function `draw_function` as the callback function.

Comment: wow, thank you very much for the detailed answer! I tried to do like you, but I ran into some difficulties:

E0135 "Practform::MyForm" does not contain a member of "draw_wrapper"
E0167 the argument of type "Practform::MyForm^" is incompatible with the parameter of type "void *"

Comment: if you know how to fix these problems, please let me know

Comment: @idk_how Unfortunately I don't know enough of C++/CLI to be able to help with the specifics of it.

Comment: that's okay. I'll try to figure it out, thanks